# Error with searching between two dates on mschart

Tags: vb.net, datetime, mschart

I have a problem with MSchart control. I have 2 fields on my database for date and time.

When I connect to my database and load X and Y values to my chart, there is no problem, but when i use search between 2 date in my query then mschart loads nothing. I'm using Text format for inDate1 and inTime1, here is my code:

```
Dim con As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel

Dim query As String = "SELECT inDate1,inTime1 FROM loginlog where personID=" + TextBox1.Text+" and inDate1 between "+ TextBox2.Text " and " + TextBox3.Text
Dim mycon As New OleDbConnection(con)
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(query, mycon)

mycon.Open()
chart1.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader()

chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "inDate1"

chart1.Series(0).YValueType = ChartValueType.Time

chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "inTime1"

chart1.DataBind()
mycon.Close()
```

Comment: You *really* do not want to use text for dates. Instead, convert them to DateTimes (e.g. with [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and pass them as SQL parameters. The remark about passing as an SQL parameter applies to *all* paramters, including the personID. It should be easy enough to find information on all that by using a search engine.

Comment: You probably need single quotes around the dates at the very least: `and inDate1 between '"+ TextBox2.Text "' and '" + TextBox3.Text & "'"`  And comment above is correct--you should really use parameters.

Comment: You also may need to cast inDate1 as a DATE if it is a datetime type: `AND (CAST ([inDate1] as DATE) BETWEEN ...`

Comment: Thanks my friends. i change the Database fields type to Date Time and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You *really* do not want to use text for dates. Instead, convert them to DateTimes (e.g. with DateTime.TryParse) and pass them as SQL parameters.The remark about passing as an SQL parameter applies to all parameters, including the personID.

So, your code could look something like:

```
Dim startDate As DateTime
Dim endDate As DateTime

If Not DateTime.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, startDate) Then
    ' there was an error parsing - do something useful
    startDate = New DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
End If

If Not DateTime.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, endDate) Then
    ' there was an error parsing - do something useful
    endDate = New DateTime(2100, 12, 31)
Else
    ' add a day to include it in the range selected in the SQL query
    endDate = endDate.AddDays(1)
End If

Dim query As String = "SELECT inDate1, inTime1 FROM loginlog WHERE personID = @PersonID AND inDate1 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate"
Dim mycon As New OleDbConnection(con)
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(query, mycon)

command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@PersonID", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Value = TextBox1.Text})
command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@StartDate", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = startDate})
command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@EndDate", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = endDate})

' now execute the query...
```